# How can I "copy" a zoom from another video?

Tags: after-effects, effects, zoom, presets, premiere-pro

This question might sound weird but I've had it for a LONG time.

Basically, is it possible to "track and copy" a **zoom** from a video and save it as a preset, so I can apply it to other videos?

For example, you can easily "track and copy" the motion of a video. All you need to do is to place trackers everywhere, and you can then paste that onto another video to make it move exactly the same way.

But is the same possible for ***zoom?*** So, for example, can I copy the iconic "zoom into face" zoom of The Office, then use that on another video?

I am talking specifically Adobe Premiere Pro or After Effects.

This question might already have been asked, but I can't find any - Everything that comes up is simply about "zoom transitions", not "zoom" itself.

Thank you! I wish I can find an answer here!